# Form input type time in millitary format with seconds (00:00:00)

Tags: html, forms, input, timestamp

I am looking at different input times here:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

here is my form where I am trying to add a time format in the scheduling textfields as time without time zone:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p class="font-weight-bold">Monday-Friday:</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="time" id="mf_start_time" class="form-control form-group w-100 mf_start_time" placeholder="Start Time">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="time" id="mf_end_time  " class="form-control form-group w-100 mf_end_time  " placeholder="End Time">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: 1]

The lists in the link does not have a military time format, I am wondering if it is possible to do so because in my table, the format is 00:00:00 hr/min/sec with no date

Table format: (time without time zone)

[image: 2]

Summary: I want to change my 12hr format input field into a 24hr format input field permanently

Comment: [Many more dupes](https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+time+24+hour+format+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: no, i explained that my databases takes in millitary time. that "duplicate" says that the time changes depending on your format. my question is different

Comment: my input type is in a 12 hr format, I would like it to be in a 24 hr format PERMANENTLY

Comment: I dont need the server i just need the input field to change format so that I can save the content of the field to my database, thats it. my save function will do the rest

Comment: the dupes does not event show it in seconds

Comment: it would be appreciated if you could advice on what to do/add for my issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487621/how-do-i-force-seconds-to-appear-on-an-html5-time-input-control/14487701

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#using_the_step_attribute) w3schools is a poor reference